# How to get texts from storyboard elements (buttons, labels) in string catalog?

Tags: string, catalog, localized

I understood, that Xcode can of course only recognise the strings which should be translated if they were previously marked with String(localized: "Your text") in my code.

However, I have not yet managed to find out how Xcode recognises texts that have been defined in the storyboard, i.e. on the user interface builder, in various elements such as buttons, labels etc. outside the code. Such texts do not appear in my file localizable.xcstrings (string catalogue) yet.

How can I persuade Xcode to include such texts in the string catalogue?

Stephan

What works for these elements is the good old .strings file, which was supposed to be replaced by String catalog since iOS15.